# C++ Eclipse Linker, /usr/bin/ld cannot find .so files

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm trying to compile a project for learning C++ and have struggled with this for a while, searching about has yielded no results. I'm trying to include .so files in another folder but the compiler (g++) cannot find the files in the directory even though they exist and Eclipse tells me it can find them. (So I know I'm not making a mistake about their location)

My console output is the following

```
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -L/home/chris/Programs/lib/SFML-2.5.1 -o space Graphics.o Physics.o main.o -llibsfml-network.so -llibsfml-graphics.so -l../../../lib/SFML-2.5.1/lib/libsfml-audio.so -llibsfml-window -l/home/chris/Programs/lib/SFML-2.5.1/lib/libsfml-system.so 
/usr/bin/ld: Physics.o: in function `std::iterator_traits<long double const*>::iterator_category std::__iterator_category<long double const*>(long double const* const&)':
/home/chris/Programs/C++/space/Debug/../SEntity.h:22: multiple definition of `createEntity(long double, long double, long double, long double, long double, int)'; Graphics.o:/home/chris/Programs/C++/space/Debug/../SEntity.h:22: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `std::iterator_traits<long double const*>::iterator_category std::__iterator_category<long double const*>(long double const* const&)':
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/vector.tcc:478: multiple definition of `createEntity(long double, long double, long double, long double, long double, int)'; Graphics.o:/home/chris/Programs/C++/space/Debug/../SEntity.h:22: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibsfml-network.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibsfml-graphics.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l../../../lib/SFML-2.5.1/lib/libsfml-audio.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibsfml-window
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/home/chris/Programs/lib/SFML-2.5.1/lib/libsfml-system.so
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've included multiple methods of finding the files but none have worked.

In Eclipse I've also added the include folder (with .h files) of the library to

Project Properties >> C/C++ General >> Paths and Symbols >> Includes

And the folder of the library (highest level folder) to

Project Properties >> C/C++ General >> Paths and Symbols >> Library Paths

Comment: you should omit `lib` prefix when linking libraries. Also you have multiple definition errors, most likely you have a non-inline function definition in header file or including cpp file.

Comment: `/home/chris/Programs/lib/SFML-2.5.1` looks like a different path from `/home/chris/Programs/lib/SFML-2.5.1/lib/libsfml-system.so` did you need to use `/home/chris/Programs/lib/SFML-2.5.1/lib` and drop the lib prefix?

Comment: @drescherjm I have a folder of libraries called lib and inside the libaries folder it also has a folder called lib so they're different folders, changing the prefix has not done anything. I tried changing the file path for Project Properties >> C/C++ General >> Paths and Symbols >> Library Paths to have the /SFML-2.5.1/lib instead of just /SFML-2.5.1